# Schedules for applications with seasonal behaviour

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I run discrete event simulations which cover more than a year. All events need to be tracked on a second time scale.
Now, I want to schedule the events according to a timetable, calculate overtime, ... and compare it to the real labor time in the end.
I thought whether there is an elegant way to implement schedules in R such that the following tasks/questions can be answered within one line of code:

- Schedule work according to a timetable.
- Given a timetable, how many labor hours do we expect per day/week/month/... Calculate the overtime per day/week/month/...
- Create simple plots to visualize working time, overtime, ... and compare it to the planned work load.

On an abstract level, assume all of the **timetables are given more or less in the following way**:

```
Name   Days_of_year     Available                             Time  
Name1  Jan-07 – Oct-18  Mon, Tues, Wed, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun  8:45 - 18:00  
Name2  Jan-01 – Dec-31  Mon, Tues, Wed, Thurs, Fri            20:00 - 7:00
```

**I am not looking for obvious answers like "create an arry and somehow you get everything out of that" but an implementation that**:

- Makes schedules independent of time resolution (days, hours, minutes, seconds).
- Schedules/timetables are not stored with redundant information.
- Any result (e.g. total year labor, ...) should be easily transferred to any given unit.
- Easy filter possibilities by month, wday, ...
- Ideally, calendar functionalities (holidays, ...) can be easily used.
- Perhaps as part of lubridate?

## Use case view ("schedule functions" indicated by s_):

- Time: s_hm(„7:45“), s_md(„Jan-23“) or s_md(„01-23“). Please note that those "times" do not make sence as dates or date-times, but in the framework of schedules they perfectly make sence!
- Interval: s_interval. See first thoughts below.
- Duration: s_interval/dhours(1) => Duration in hours
- Functions:

  - Max(), Min() on any s_interval
  - %s_in%

    - Given a date, when does somebody work:
      date(s) %s_in% s_interval
      => return TRUE/FALSE (array)
    - Given a schedule, when is somebody available in an interval:
      s_interval %s_in% interval
      => return class interval - a subset of interval!
    - Given an interval, was the labor according to schedule? Calculate the idle-, over- and working time:
      interval %s_in% s_interval
      => return class s_interval
  - Given two schedules, consider them as one unit. How is idle-, over- and working time distributed:
    (s_interval1 %+% s_interval2)
    => return class s_interval

## Some thoughts:

`schedule` in case of planning labor time:

```
s_interval $tzone   UTC
    $daysofyear 286 days        (Better alternative: format month-day e.g. Jan-07 – Oct-18) 
    $wday           Mon, Tues, ... Sun  (According to the start time of a shift/lecture...)
    $time           12 h            (Better alternative: format time span* e.g. 8:00 – 18:00. NOT period which results in hours)
    $overtime       0 h         (A priori, a schedule does not plan overtime)
    $idle           0 h         (A priori, a schedule only plans labor time)
```

`schedule` when real time-data is available:

```
s_interval$tzone    UTC
    $daysofyear 286 days                (Better alternative: format month-day e.g. Jan-07 – Oct-18) 
    $wday           c(Mon, Tues, Wed, ...)      (According to the start time of a shift/lecture...)
    $time           c(12 h, 1 h, 0.5 h, ...)        (Better alternative: format time span* e.g. 8:00 – 18:00. NOT period which results in hours)
    $overtime       c(2 h, 0 h, -1 h, ...)      total time = time + overtime. Array of lubridate intervals*?
    $idle           c(4 h, 8 h, 0h, ...)        pure working_time = time – idle + overtime. Array of lubridate intervals*?
```

`* Use intervals not periods such that interval/dhours(1) possible.`

If the tzone is the same we could calculate e.g.

```
s_interval1 %+% s_interval2 =  
s_interval$tzone    UTC
    $daysofyear    286 days,            123 days        
    $wday           c(Mon, Tues, Wed, ...),     c(Sat, Sun)
    $time          c(12 h, 1 h, 0.5 h, ...),    c(-1 h, 2.5 h)
    $overtime      c(2 h, 0 h, -1 h, ...),      c(0 h, 5 h)
    $idle          c(4 h, 8 h, 0h, ...),        c(4 h, 8 h)
```

There are related posts about this topic [visualization of schedules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280789/visualizing-a-staffing-schedules-in-r) with some interesting answers concerning `timeline` and `gantt` packages and [how to filter dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516157/how-to-filter-or-subset-specific-date-and-time-intervals-in-r-lubridate).
However, they are not very conclusive.

As I am quite new to R, I don't know, how to start such a task the best way and understanding the structure of a package like lubridate is quite advanced...

Comment: I am working on the task... Hopefully with success!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a package which gives the desired functionality (even with plots). At the moment, the package is private, but let me know if you are interested.